# What GPS unit can I use to track myself all day for a 10 day trip?

Tags: gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logging GPS and Accelerometer Data - Device Suggestion?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15168/logging-gps-and-accelerometer-data-device-suggestion)

I will be visiting China this October as part of a field studies course and I want to be able to take the opportunity to try out something unusual (maybe usual?). I want to be able to track my movement throughout China using the GPS unit attached to my bag/clothing. I want something that will be reliable/accurate and where the battery lasts a decent amount of time (might go without being able to charge 8 hours at a time). Bonus, this GPS will stay with me for the years to come so I will think of it as an investment, so my budget is fairly loose at the moment.

I've drawn some inspiration from these maps:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iC56P-Ro4PY
- http://www.flickr.com/photos/walkingsf/sets/72157629014750905/
- http://www.flickr.com/photos/walkingsf/sets/72157628738161697/

Anyways, just thought I'd poke around in gis.se because there should be a fair amount of geographers in here with GPS usage experience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out the IBlue 737/747. It's been suggested at another question in this site. From the original [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/18752/292):

> IBlue 737/747 are great passive GPS collectors. No screen/map (there's
>   your primary power drain... not the GPS). A little bigger than a
>   Matchbox car. Rechargable 23-26hr cell-phone battery. Collects
>   user-selectable items (lat, long, altitude, speed, LDOP, PDOP, etc).
>   Customized collection time or spacing (every x seconds or positino
>   change: 10 feet, 50 feet, etc).

Comment: This is a perfect solution, thanks for pointing me towards that question! Already decided to pick up one of their current models :D

Comment: That's a nice example of using our site for research, R.K.  I'm sorry to lose your reply by closing this as a duplicate, but it really is a perfect match and we don't want a proliferation of near-identical threads.

Comment: It's okay. Still getting used to the culture here. I really need to hang out at the meta more often. Will flag questions next time :)

Comment: The moderators *appreciate* flags.  We wish more people would raise them :-).