# GPS device taking pictures and saving heading + HDOP?

Tags: openstreetmap, cartography, gps, mobile, photos

I'm looking for a device that can do all of the following:

- Take picture
- Save lat-long GPS position + *heading* (angle to North) of picture [so need tilt-compensated 3D compass], in exif or other format (save tilt as well if possible)
- Save *precision-related GPS (NMEA) fields*, as many as possible (at least HDOP, other if possible)
- If possible: display OSM maps (better if I can put [my own tiles](http://www.outdoormaps.org/?p=39))

Ideally HDOP and the like should go into both exif of the pictures and gpx track, but post-processing (gpscorrelate or the like) is OK.

I would need to know this ASAP to buy the device and learn how to use it: it's for an 80-day alpine OSM mapping party, starting early June 2012! See here: 
http://www.outdoormaps.org
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ViaAlpina

There are already some data on this long high-distance trail, but they lack accuracy estimates. Heading will make the pictures much more valuable.

Thanks!

Mayeul Kauffmann

(PS: I've seen this question: [Device for Logging GPS and Accelerometer Data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15168/logging-gps-and-accelerometer-data-device-suggestion)  but I need heading and HDOP)

Comment: You might want to add your price range and GPS accuracy desires.

Comment: Right. Price range would be between 300 and 800 euros (above 500 especially if there are additional functionalities that could be useful). GPS accuracy of a recreational GPS (10-20m most of the time with clear sky) is OK. I do not mind adding an external antenna (including on the head) if needed.

Comment: Sounds ideal for a smartphone - try GPSEssentials on Android; I cannot confirm that the camera tool saves HDOP and heading in EXIF, but the developer may be responsive.

Comment: I'd love a smarthphone. I could not find a way to ask the developer of GPSEssentials here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mictale.gpsessentials&hl=en

There is the "leave review" options and there are more than 40 pages of review, some with questions, but I failed to see any answer from the developer 8-(

Then, I will still need to find the device that supports this (android needs to get access to these, which is hardware- and drivers-dependent)

Comment: Iphone 4S does a lot of what I need:

Comment: Iphone 4S:

-saves GPS Img Direction in exif:
http://www.brianklug.org/2011/11/a-quick-analysis-of-exif-data-from-apples-iphone-4s-camera-samples/

- has this app (thanks Elena):http://hrtapps.com/theodolite/

- could not find anything recent on hdop in Iphone's GPS, but found this: http://groups.google.com/group/chargecar/browse_thread/thread/ff1a0b5601106eca/f8667d1746456417?pli=1

Still it's very expensive (unlocked version) and not open system 8-(

I'm looking at Neo Freerunner, GTA04 (camera driver not working yet), Nokia n900 (runs Debian), Android

Comment: @Mayeul - many, many Android options out there - the only real problem with them as field data devices would be battery life. We're looking at adapting them for all kinds of data collection, including photographs and tracks, so would be keen to see what you end up with!

Answer (score 2):

The [Casio Exilim EX-H20G](http://www.trustedreviews.com/Casio-Exilim-EX-H20G_Digital-Camera_review) has a built in GPS and compass; both of which are saved in EXIF tags.  It also has a "hybrid GPS" mode that uses an accelerometer to augment GPS when reception is poor.  It does not have any track logging ability.

Its worth doing a search for the model on Flickr and downloading some example raw images.  This will let you see exactly what data is stored.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know you could search by camera:
http://www.flickr.com/cameras/
you have to be logged-in to see the exif, then click on "Actions" button. I found a dozen cameras that have GPS and heading support, here:
http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?by=feature

Comment: For those cameras I searched flickr, found only 2: Panasonic DM-zs7 (saves gps, heading not shown in flickr); Sony DSC-hx5V (found 3 pictures with "GPS Img Direction"). Can't save track (dschx5v_handbook.pdf p104GB).
flickr DOES NOT show all cameras in list: Sony DSC-TX100V not shown, but this DSC-TX100V image has heading: http://www.flickr.com/photos/oceanyamaha/6940034429/meta/in/photostream

Answer (score 1):

If smartphones don't have the capabilities you want, you might look into the Garmin Montana or Oregon GPS handhelds ([Garmin](https://buy.garmin.com/shop/shop.do?cID=145)).  They both claim to geotag photos, but I'm not sure how much info they include.  You'll probably have to call their technical staff to get an answer.

Another option may be a [Trimble Juno](http://www.trimble.com/mappingGIS/juno3.aspx?dtID=applications&).  They are an entry-level mapping grade handheld.  Price could be fairly high to get all the right software on it ($1000+), but I'm betting it supports more info in geotagged photos.  You'll have to contact their technical staff to get more details I think.

Comment: Orgeon x50 [550] should support it:
"heading to geotagged photo EXIF information (see GPSImgDirection and GPSImgDirectionRef tags)"
Cf:
http://garminoregon.wikispaces.com/message/view/Camera/14802505
http://garminoregon.wikispaces.com/Camera
Still to verify:
-gpx saves hdop?
-Direction based on compass, not on GPS?
http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10814/what-do-the-global-angle-and-global-altitude-in-the-exif-info-mean says:
"The angle is the bearing in which the camera was facing at the time - this can either be measured with an electronic compass or interpolated from two GPS fixes"

Comment: I know that there is also a roundabout way of adding your own map tiles to some Garmin units (Custom Maps - http://www.garmin.com/us/products/onthetrail/custommaps).  It may not be compatible with your OSM stuff, but worth looking into.

Comment: I've asked for Oregon on a dedicated wiki: gpx does not save hdop, heading source is uncertain, see:
http://garminoregon.wikispaces.com/message/view/Camera/51984038
http://garminoregon.wikispaces.com/message/view/Camera/51983704

Comment: Bummer. Sounds like the Garmins don't have the capability you need.  The Juno might, but cost may be prohibitive.

Answer (score 0):

I found these Android apps, would be great if people who have a smartphone could test and report here if all the requirements are filled with their specific smartphone:

OSMtracker (multipurpose, w/ HDOP)
https://code.google.com/p/osmtracker-android/

Imageotag - http://imageotag.appspot.com/

Mytracks (saves GPS tracks) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.maps.mytracks

GPSSmid (multipurpose) http://sourceforge.net/projects/gpsmid/files/ Maybe the most powerful of all apps, but needs a JVM (so works on non-android devices too).

OSMtracker, GPSmid & Mytracks are libre & open source. GPSmid & OSMtracker have active open communities.